# Why does Ulysses Klaue think this about Wanda?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

During *Avengers: Age of Ultron* Ulysses Klaue has the following conversation with Wanda:

> **Wanda:** Everybody's afraid of something.
> **Ulysses Klaue:** Cuttlefish! Deep sea fish, they make lights, disco lights, whomp, whomp, whomp, to hypnotize their prey, and then whomp! I saw a documentary; it was terrifying. So, if you're going to fiddle with my brain, and make me see a giant Cuttlefish, then I know you don't do business and I know you're not in charge and I only deal with the man in charge!

Why does Klaue think it proves anything? Why doesn't Wanda use this weakness to her advantage?

Comment: Just for the record, I wrote the quote as a spoiler but someone edited it so it will always be visible.

Comment: You don't really need spoiler tag on a 5-year-old movie. You can expect people to have seen it by now.

Comment: I did. But not because of the film's age, age has nothing to do with it. Age doesn't directly influence what is a spoiler and what isn't. I removed the spoiler block because this dialgoue is, for any and all purposes, not a spoiler in any way anyone could come up with. What would even *be* the spoiler here, that Klaue doesn't like Cuttlefish? Even more so, the dialogue is the *core* of what the question is about. Without it the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Also, anyone who hasn't watched Age of Ultron and goes into a question about it ... deserves to be spoiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, he was just mocking the twins at this point. In essence, he's saying: "I'm not afraid of you. I know that you're not acting by yourself. Stop wasting my time and let me talk to your boss".

Full quote:

> **Klaue:** Yeah. The enhanced. Strucker's prized pupils. Want a candy? ...
> Oh, sorry to hear about Strucker. But then, he knew what kind of world he was helping to create. Human life, not a growth market.
> *(Twins are visibly surprised)*
> You didn't know? Is this your first time? Intimidating someone? I'm afraid, I'm not that afraid.
> **Wanda:** Everybody's afraid of something.
> **Klaue:** Cuttlefish! Deep-sea fish, they make lights, disco lights, whomp, whomp, whomp, to hypnotize their prey, and then whomp! I saw a documentary; it was terrifying. So, if you're going to fiddle with my brain, and make me see a giant Cuttlefish, then I know you don't do business and I know you're not in charge and I only deal with the man in charge!

The first monologue says a lot. Klaue is more informed than Maximoffs and knows everything about them. He also knows that they are too inexperienced to track him down by themselves. Somebody's sent them to get something from him. He'd like to know more about this person.

When Wanda tries to scare him down, he mocks her with a deliberately silly fear of cuttlefish. This is his way of showing that he's not scared of her and her powers and wants to talk business.

Comment: But if really he was afraid of cuttlefish, whether or not it sounded silly to himself, why didn't she use it against him?

Comment: @LWC She didn't have enough time to try, Ultron showed up right after that. We don't know what would happen if she did, we can only speculate. Anyway, even if she starts torturing him with his worst fears (cuttlefish or something else) he still knows that she's not the one in charge.

Comment: @LWC I think it's quite clear that he isn't actually afraid of cuttlefish.

Comment: @TheLeathalCarrot - I think he is, due to him having a tendency to share truths about himself that are hilariously irrelevant, such as his offer of his mixtape Soundcloud link to Agent Ross in BP ;-)